# How to detect text entry for a h:inputText control

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page built using Prime Faces 3.3 and need to be able to enable a component when a user starts typing in text in an input text field. The text field is implemented as a h:inputText component - I tried various listeners such as

valueChangeListener="#{managedbean.onValueChange}"

but the value only gets received once the form is submitted not when the text gets changed.
Is there a way to detect this ?

Thanks

Comment: public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

 UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
 String clientId = component.getClientId();
 
 if ("SelectItemComponent".equals(clientId)
  //Enable Another component here 
 }

 if ("TextFieldComponent".equals(clientId)) {
  String textFieldValue = (String) event.getNewValue();
  //Enable Another component here 
 }
}

Comment: Its hard to tell what you're trygin to do. Post your xhtml and java code in your questino.

Comment: I have a input text field on the page - how do I add a listener so that when a user enters some text the middle tier will immediately get notified and some code can get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you'd do

**XHTML page**

```
<h:form id="form">  

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">  


        <p:inputText id="counter">  
            <p:ajax event="keyup" 
                    listener="#{counterBean.increment}"/>  
        </p:inputText>  


    </h:panelGrid>  

</h:form>
```

**BACKBEA**

```
import java.io.Serializable;  

public class CounterBean implements Serializable{  


    public void increment() {  
        //do something 
    }  
}
```

Whenever you type something it will call the `increment` method.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good solution to the issue and it works for me but it sends too many calls to the server - is there any event I can capture to make it simpler ?

Comment: This was your requirement. How would you like this to be simpler?